# Change Default URL in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics-4

I have a property in Google Analytics 4 that I would like to change the default URL for.  In my searches, all the instructions point to the the Property Settings where there should be a Default URL field.  However, I don't see that field (see below).  Is there a new location with which one can change the default URL?  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: you mean the website URL?

Comment: @SanjayChoudhary yes

Comment: looks like you need to delete existing data stream and create a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Sanjay, the URLs are now in the Property under Data Streams.  It doesn't appear that a data stream URL can be changed, so if you have a new URL, a new Data Stream will have to be created.

[GA4 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No256.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the stream url by doing the following:

**1. Go to the Data Streams panel in the Admin Options for the Property.**

[image: Data Stream Option]

**2.Click on the arrow for the data stream.**

[image: Data Stream Arrow]

**3. Click on the crayon button to edit the stream settings.**

[image: Crayon to edit]

**4. You can now edit the link under the stream URL.**

[image: Edit URL here]